# SQL, How to correctly sum in while loop and write it to table by weeks number

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop, sum, grouping

I have data that I need to sum properly, but can't quite figure out how:

```
create table #Test
(
Job [nvarchar](20) 
,[Order] [nvarchar](20) 
,WeekNumber int
,startday date
,endday date
,WeeklyHrs decimal(17, 5)
,WhatTheClientWants decimal(17, 5)
,PreviousHrs decimal(17, 5)
)

INSERT INTO #Test
VALUES 
(1,1,1,'2022-05-09','2022-05-15',172,NULL,0),
(1,1,2,'2022-05-16','2022-05-22',9,NULL,0),
(1,2,1,'2022-05-09','2022-05-15',9,NULL,0),
(1,2,999,NULL,NULL,32.5,NULL,32.5),
(1,5,1,'2022-05-09','2022-05-15',162,NULL,0),
(1,5,2,'2022-05-16','2022-05-22',20,NULL,0),
(1,5,3,'2022-05-16','2022-05-22',0,NULL,0),
(1,6,2,'2022-05-16','2022-05-22',1,NULL,0),
(1,3,999,NULL,NULL,32.5,NULL,54)
```

So client has two parameters, @startdate, @enddate, and between those parameters I form weeks. Like 09.05.2022 - 15.05.2022 - week 1, 16.05.2022, 22.05.2022 - week 2.
Depends on that, I had my grouping later, but now, new task appeared.
I need so that Week Two had its hours plus hours form week one, week three (there could be a lot of weeks) has Hours from week one and two and three and so on...
I tried Update with while but it didn't quiet work, then I tried Window Function, but I am doing something wrong:

```
declare @MaxWeek int = (select top 1 max(WeekNumber) over (PARTITION BY job) from #Test where WeekNumber <> 999)
DECLARE @i int = 0

WHILE (@i <= @MaxWeek)
BEGIN
UPDATE #Test
set WhatTheClientWants = (select sum(FullHrs) from #Test group by Job, WeekNumber)
set @i= @i+1
END
```

I imagine that there should be may be some kind of case that if week one, its just hours, but if not, some kind of sum

```
WHILE (@i <= @MaxWeek)
BEGIN
UPDATE #Test
set WhatTheClientWants = FullHrs from #Test where WeekNumber = @i 
set @i= @i+1
END
```

but what case I can't figure out...

What it should looks like:
[image: 1]

Would appreciate any help!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: Hello! I use SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a window function to do this:

```
SELECT testtable.*, 
    SUM(WeeklyHours) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY startday ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS WhatTheClientWants
FROM #test as testtable
```

That's taking each group of records that share the same "partition" (or [Order] column value), sorting them by `startday` and then summing them all together up to the current row. A cumulative sum inside of a partition.

While it's always tempting to think "WHILE LOOP!" as a solution, in a database that's almost never needed. In over a decade in this field, I've only had to resort to a while loop once for a very procedural solution that had no set based alternative.

---

Just noticed the nulls for NULL startday in the new column. Clobbering this with a UNION ALL should suffice:

```
SELECT testtable.*, 
    SUM(WeeklyHrs) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY startday ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS WhatTheClientWants
FROM #test as testtable
WHERE StartDay IS NOT NULL 
UNION ALL
SELECT testtable.*, NULL
FROM #test as testtable
WHERE StartDay IS NULL
```

Comment: Hey! That is the magical thing you wrote there! Thank you very much, thousand times I think that I need to dive into window functions a little bit deeper that max or simple sum. I try to implement it into my procedure, but it give me an error (it did it before I used window function too) that it wants me to Group by WeeklyHours field, and that obviously brakes everything... Is there some knows error when it ask you to group summed field from window function?

Comment: I'm not 100% following you, but a good rule to follow is to not combine GROUP BY and windows functions. You can, but it makes everything confusing. If you need to also perform a GROUP BY for another level of aggregation, it's best to do that in a subquery or in a main query (if windowing is done in a subquery).

Comment: Yeah, that is a good rule to follow, got rid of grouping, did it elsewhere and everything is working as needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the solution from JNevill

```
select Job 
,[Order] 
,WeekNumber 
,startday 
,endday 
,WeeklyHrs 
,sum(WeeklyHrs) OVER (PARTITION BY [Order] ORDER BY [Order], WeekNumber )
,PreviousHrs 
from #test
```

As you appear to be only partitioning on `[Order]`

Incidentally, this may not match your expected results - those results did not match the data you provided at all - may be something else for you to check

Comment: Thanks! That works too, when I changed a little bit a structure of my table for grouping separately from window function, this one ( I actually tried it before, but it was wrong at that point), now works too. Thank you very much!